# Mobile responsive interactive advice needed

Tags: responsive-design, interactive

I am hoping someone can help me with an interactive issue. I'm trying to create a mobile responsive interactive.
Each blue and orange shaded area in the attached graphic needs to click to reveal another image over the original image. 
I've done this the old school way with javascript and image maps and it works a treat on a large screen, but isn't at all mobile friendly.
e.g

```
onclick="MM_swapImage('Image1','','one1.jpg',1)"
onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"
```

So I've tried doing it in SVG with javascript but I can't get that going.
Can someone tell me the best way to go about doing this so it's mobile friendly?

This is image I am using: [image: here]